# HaxeDevelop Problem "Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader"

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm currently new in Haxe, when i open up HaxeDevelop software it shows this error code:

> Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible
> causes are invalid stream or object version change between
> serialization and deserialization.
>
> at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
> at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
> handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
> isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
> serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
> isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
> PluginCore.Utilities.ObjectSerializer.InternalDeserialize(String file,
> Type type)    at
> PluginCore.Utilities.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(String file, Object
> obj, Boolean checkValidity)

Can someone help me?

[Here's the Window Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kizlw.png)

I also did trying reinstalling it several times, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What version you're using? Try to [download dev version](https://flashdevelop.org/downloads/builds/) of HaxeDevelop or FlashDevelop (it should work same)

Comment: I was using HaxeDevelop 5.3.2, by the way the HaxeDevelop development version doesn't work and the FlashDevelop development version also doesn't work, thanks for your answer anyways.